# Receiving/sending signals via Bluetooth antenna

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a possibility to read signals from Bluetooth antenna? I want to do a kind of radar.
I also want to sending signals bytes by bytes.

Can I do it on Android?

Comment: You can get some directions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **no**

Long answer: yes, but you have to root your device, recompile kernel and write new bluetooth driver and firmware for your bluetooth module. No way to do it using only Android SDK.