# Using smartphone's TV antenna as an antenna for sending and receiving RF signals

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, firmware

I saw a video on youtube talking about a project to see people through the wall in this [website with MIT references and videos](http://rfcapture.csail.mit.edu/) and I thought it would be interesting if I could make an android app on my phone. My cell phone is the LG L Bello which has an Analog TV antenna and I think it increases my chances of it working or not? Do I need to open my phone to apply changes for this to work? I want to know how I do this, or how I find someone/forum/tutorials that can help me with this task or just start.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800252/receiving-sending-signals-via-bluetooth-antenna)

Things I already know about this:

- I know that I probably have to root the phone.
- In other posts, I realized that I have to recompile the kernel and write a new Bluetooth driver and firmware for your Bluetooth module,
- How do I do this (Posts / Tutorials)? and then how do I use this in my android app?

Comment: What is your background ? You are mixing a lot of technology here (TV Antenna,RF, Bluetooth), do you know the differnces between those ?.These kind of project requires some advanced skills to begin with. what kind of help you demand ?

Comment: I know the difference between bluetooth for wifi and I have ideas of what the cell phone's TV antenna does, but something I know is that they all work with RF, so I don't know if in practice this is viable or possible (For hardware or firmware issues or both). I have knowledge (when I don't know I can search about these things) of electronics and C.I, assembly, C, C ++, linux kernel. I just don't know java for android but i can get help from a friend for that.